# How to force background color on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to apply a background color to a listed item from the .dropped_menu class. It works ok in Chrome and IE, but for some reason it doesn't work in Firefox, which applies a transparent background. It's a dropdown menu that is "hidden" and then made "visible" with jQuery. I'm not sure if that matters since I believe it's an issue with Firefox applying default styles, background color in this case. I have researched and I haven't found a solution. Thanks for the help!

HTML:

```
<ul class="dropped_menu">

    <li id="show_home1" class="home_block"><a href="#" id="home_hover1">........</a></li>
    <li id= "show_gallery1"class="gallery_block"><a href="#" id="gallery_hover1">........</a></li>
    <li id="show_events1" class="events_block"><a href="#" id="events_hover1">.........</a></li>
    <li id="about_side1"><a href="#" id="link_5"></a></li>
    <li id="show_donate1" class="join_block" ><a href="members.html" id="join_hover1" style="font-size:1em;">Get Involved</a></li>
    <li id="show_about1"  class="about_block"><a href="about.html" id="about_hover1">Our Story</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="extra"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="extra"></a></li>

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.dropped_menu li {
  background-color: black !important;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Looks the same in Chrome and Firefox in this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/oo1ytfjx/

Comment: Thanks for that. I know, it looks ok. I suppose it's some bug happening in the rest of the code that is overwriting the style. However, I wonder if it's a browser compatibility issue, since it works ok on IE, Chrome and Safari

Comment: We'd need to see more code to see what's interfering.  If you could create a Fiddle or CodePen demonstrating the issue, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine. Maby you shuold try to run firefox in "private browsing mode" which will clear cashed css file.

Comment: Thanks guys, the code seems fine, I have tried the private browsing mode but it's the same. I'm going to go through the whole code once more because it's a bit long to post it all here. Hopefully I'll find a solution. Thank you!